# DocuSign demo account envelopes list_status_changes returning USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

Using DocuSign python SDK to get an application JWT token on a sandbox environment and then list status changes of envelopes. API call response is 400 Bad Request: USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED.

I've done the one-time access grant for first-time JWT token request (using `APIClient.get_authorization_uri`).

`APIClient.request_jwt_application_token` produces valid token (checked with jwt.io and Public/Private keys)

Config/parameters:

- oauth_host_name: account-d.docusign.com
- Redirect URI: https://www.docusign.com/api

I've searched through similar questions. When they refer to production environments, the solution is to adjust the sub-domain of the baseURL (na, eu, etc). However, this shouldn't be an issue for demo environments.

API client:

```
api_client = ds.ApiClient(oauth_host_name='account-d.docusign.com')
```

OAuth URL:

```py
oauth_login_url = api_client.get_authorization_uri(dict_secrets['DSIntegratorKey'],
                                                   scopes=['signature impersonation'],
                                                   redirect_uri='https://www.docusign.com/api',
                                                   response_type='code')
```

JWT token request:

```py
api_client.request_jwt_application_token(client_id=dict_secrets['DSIntegratorKey'], expires_in=3600,
                                         oauth_host_name=api_client.get_oauth_host_name(),
                                         private_key_bytes=dict_secrets['DSPrivateKey'].encode('utf-8'))
ds.configuration.api_client = api_client
```

Troublesome line:

```py
envelopes_api = ds.EnvelopesApi()
envelopes_information = envelopes_api.list_status_changes(dict_secrets['DSAccountID'],
                                                          from_date=last_run_str, status='completed')
```

Error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\apis\envelopes_api.py", line 6884, in list_status_changes
    (data) = self.list_status_changes_with_http_info(account_id, **kwargs)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\apis\envelopes_api.py", line 7001, in list_status_changes_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_client.py", line 354, in call_api
    _return_http_data_only, collection_formats, _preload_content, _request_timeout)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_client.py", line 170, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_client.py", line 377, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_response.py", line 200, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\docusign_esign\client\api_response.py", line 191, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
docusign_esign.client.api_exception.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Length': '132', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '27b02745-8b7a-49e5-8657-f12a8eca6efe', 'Date': 'Tue, 06 Aug 2019 14:42:50 GMT', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'})
HTTP response body: b'{\r\n  "errorCode": "USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",\r\n  "message": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid. invalid_request"\r\n}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a support call with DocuSign, it turned out that some attributes of the api_client and the envelopes_api weren't being set properly. Solution was to set them explicitly:

- `api_client.set_base_path('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi')`
- `envelopes_api = ds.EnvelopesApi(api_client)`
- `envelopes_api.api_client.host = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi'` - this wasn't being passed from api_client to envelopes_api, therefore the calls were going to prod instead of demo
- alternatively, set host when instantiating api_client: `api_client = ds.ApiClient(host='https://demo.docusign.net/restapi')`

Answer (score 0):

your redirect url does not look correct. 
For one thing, redirect url should be your own app url, not DocuSign.
That url that you have there (https://www.docusign.com/api) doesn't look valid to me either. Please check this again.

Comment: The redirect URI is the one set up on the integration key in Admin on the DocuSign account. It used to work with the previous version of the SDK. Can you give me an example of a URL that points to an app? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: if you are working on your local box, an example could be http://localhost:8080 if your app runs there. It can be any url, but it won't be the docusign url, as your app is not hosted in docusign.com

Comment: I tried using a different URL than the one specified in the Admin panel and got an error. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: When I open the auth url in a browser, I get "The redirect URI supplied with the request is not in the list of valid URIs configured with this client application"

Comment: you have to go back to the developer sandbox, go to admin, find the keys page and add this url to your integration key

Comment: you need to make sure you put your own app's url in the list. it won't be docusign.com

Comment: Added https://demo.docusign.net/ (DocuSign support suggested using that) to the redirect URIs, tried that, and still get the same error as originally

Comment: ok, not sure who you talked to in support, but they gave you the wrong advice. the url you need is your own app. I assume you are building a web app? and when you test it, what url do you see in your browser? localhost something? that's what you need

Comment: I'm using a python linux-based Function app in Azure, which is meant to run on a schedule every night. DocuSign support said " Because you're using JWT authentication the Redirect URI isn't actually a factor here. If you were using Authorization Code Grant then it would need to be a URL for localhost address you're sending from or a URI used by your application - not a DocuSign URL Demo or otherwise."

Comment: ok, so what is the current issue? are you still getting the error that says "The redirect URI supplied with the request is not in the list of valid URIs configured with this client application" ? because that means your url that you are redirecting to in the request is different than what you set in the IK in DocuSign Admin

Comment: The error is still as described in the original post - USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. The ticket with DocuSign support has been escalated to Tier 3.

Comment: can you check your RSA private key and make sure it's valid and that the exact same key that was produced in DocuSign admin is the one you have in your app?

Comment: Had a call with DocuSigh support, will post an answer with what turned out to be the issue